# Sales > Order 'Processing' status

Tags: orders, php

Good morning,

We are currently using **Magento** and trying to list '**Processing**' orders as default. 
We have located the status dropdown column but can't figure out how to set '**Processing**' as default.

We would love some help on this,
Thank you.

```
$this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));
```

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to see only the processing orders when clicking `Sales->Orders` and then see the rest if you choose to change the filter?

Comment: Morning @Marius, This is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

**to**

```
Copy app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

Then goto function  `__construct` add below code to after `parent::__construct()`
add

```
$this->setDefaultFilter(array('status'=>'processing'));
```

Comment: Morning Amit, I copied the code above direct into
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
As we didn't have a 
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
file or document, everything seems to be working.

Thank you:)